# ListView changing CheckBox visibility via DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` where each line shows a `CheckBox` and 2 `TextBlock`s.
It's bound to an `ObservableCollection` where each item has a IsDuplicate property.
All the data binding works and I have a `DataTrigger` that turns the entire line red when the property is true. That works.

My problem is this:
In addition to turning the line red I also want change the `Visibility` property of the `CheckBox` (but only the CheckBox) when IsDuplicate is true.

The following code turns the line red but the `CheckBox` `Visibility` remains unchanged.
I tried a `TargetName` on the setter but I get an error telling me "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter."

How can I achieve that only the `CheckBox` `Visibility` property gets set to `Hidden` when IsDuplicate is true?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SizeChanged="ListViewSizeChanged" Loaded="ListViewLoaded" >
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDuplicate}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="CheckBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn Width="30" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="Checker" >
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" Header="File" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="260" Header="URL" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding VideoUrl}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Download URL" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DownloadUrl}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `DataTemplate` for the `CheckBox` with the following. That should do the trick:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" >
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDuplicate}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```